# Keeping screen turned on for certain pages

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a portable project so do not have direct access to native code.

I have an interface in my project that allows me to access native objects in the Android/iOS projects. We use this primarily for playing audio.

Android, for example, has things like

```
Window w = new Window();
w.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

However the main issue would be accessing a `Window` object. I could pass a `Xamarin.Forms.Page` object to the native code, but there would be no way (I don't think) to cast it to a native Android `Window` object to access the flags.

Is there a way to do this with a portable project?

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534562/7149454

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't do this without platform specific services or renderers. A portable project will have to call platform specific code in order to achieve this.

From that platform specific code, either as a [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) or [`Renderer`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), you can access the `Window` object through the `Forms.Context`. The `Forms.Context` is your Android `Activity`, through which you can reach the Window object.

On Android it works like this:

```cs
Android.Views.Window window = (Forms.Context as Activity).Window;
window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

On iOS you can try this ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled)):

```cs
UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work perfectly! I suppose I should have asked about both... Any idea how this is done on iOS? Just a note, `window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);` didn't seem to work, but `window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);` does work well

Comment: Oh, you are right, didn't notice that. I've updated the answer for iOS and fixed the Android version.

Comment: Ah ok, I was just giving that a shot right now, I'll let you know if it works

Comment: In Android now I get 'Forms.Context' is obsolete: 'Context is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use a local context instead.' How do I have to do this without Forms.Context

Comment: @KeesDapperens: You could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523482/426227) for `DependencyService`. In a `Renderer` there is a `Context` parameter in the constructor. I used the `DependencyService` because with the `Renderer` changing back to the defaults (screen lock is on again) never happened.

Answer (score 5):

Now there is a plugin doing exactly what Tim wrote

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screen-lock

simple source code is here

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/KeepScreenOnViewModel.cs

using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace Samples.ViewModel
{
    public class KeepScreenOnViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public KeepScreenOnViewModel()
        {
            RequestActiveCommand = new Command(OnRequestActive);
            RequestReleaseCommand = new Command(OnRequestRelease);
        }

        public bool IsActive => DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn;

        public ICommand RequestActiveCommand { get; }

        public ICommand RequestReleaseCommand { get; }

        void OnRequestActive()
        {
            DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = true;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsActive));
        }

        void OnRequestRelease()
        {
            DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = false;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsActive));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the link work for anyone?

Comment: @testing github links can change often. Obviously was working at the time 3 years a go. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Forms Android.
Renders file I included below code

```
Window window = (Forms.Context as Activity).Window;
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```