# Xamarin Forms - Disable auto-lock when the app is open

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to disable auto-lock when my app is open. How can I do that?

Comment: this will be platform specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661004/how-to-disable-enable-the-sleep-mode-programmatically-in-ios

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The answer below was a little old the better and easy way to do it now is using essentials and setting the following property:

```
DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn= true;
```

**OG ANSWER**

For **iOS**, you need to override the `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your Appdelegate class:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
       UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;
       ....
    }
```

For **Android**, you need to do the following things in your MainActivity for it:

you have to declare this uses-permission on AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Create a global field for WakeLock `using static Android.OS.PowerManager;`;

```
private WakeLock wakeLock;
```

And in your OnResume:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Full, "My Lock");
wakeLock.Acquire();
```

Just remember to release this lock when your application is paused or destroyed by  doing this:

```
wakeLock.Release();
```

Usually, it's suggested to call the **acquire** method inside the **onResume()** of your activity and the **release** method in **onPause()**. This way we guarantee that our application still performs well in the case of being paused or resumed.

Comment: I saw an article about using xamarin essentials i dont know if that solution is implemented in all my views or do I have to implement it one by one

Comment: the article is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screen-lock?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms

Comment: You have to implement it in just one, MainActivity for Android and Appdelegate for iOS!! Are you sure you read the answer?

Comment: I mean the code in the article do I have to implement it once or one by one?

Comment: I am not sure i have not used this API of Xamarin Essentials but i have posted the answer of what i have used and what works well for me

Comment: For iOS can't you just set true/false UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled at runtime?..

Comment: @NickKovalsky You can in native iOS but not when you are in your Xamarin forms code now can you?

Comment: Yeah that's what i do in xamarin, ill post an answer for this

Comment: Added an answer with the solution im actually using

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you for your answer this one works. Can you help me with the logic of my synchronization? the link is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581483/how-to-fix-bi-directional-synchronization

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto sure give me a min to have a look

Answer (score 12):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/xamarin/essentials/device-display?tabs=android

Just need to set `DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn` to true/false in any page and it will work. There is no need to go into individual platform.

You'll have to set permission WAKE_LOCK in Android though.

Comment: The documentations don't mention a need for Wake_Lock!

Answer (score 4):

**Xamarin.Forms:**

```
//show something important, do not sleep
DependencyService.Get<INativeTasks>().ExecuteTask("cannotSleep");

//can put in OnDisappearing event
DependencyService.Get<INativeTasks>().ExecuteTask("canSleep");
```

Native tasks helper:

```
 public interface INativeTasks
    {
        ...
        void ExecuteTask(string task, object param=null);
        ...
    }
```

**Android:**

Global variables and other..

```
public class DroidCore
{
    private static DroidCore instance;
    public static DroidCore Current
    {
        get { return instance ?? (instance = new DroidCore()); }
    }

    public static Window MainWindow { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
...        
DroidCore.Current.MainView = this.Window.DecorView;
...
}
```

Native helpers:

```
public class NativeTasks : INativeTasks
    {
    public void ExecuteTask(string task, object param = null)
    {
            switch (task)
            {

                ... //any native stuff you can imagine

            case "cannotSleep":
                DroidCore.MainWindow.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
                break;

            case "canSleep":
                DroidCore.MainWindow.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

**iOS:**

Native helpers:

```
public class NativeTasks : INativeTasks
    {
    public void ExecuteTask(string task, object param = null)
    {
            switch (task)
            {

                ... //any native stuff you can imagine

            case "cannotSleep":
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;
                break;

            case "canSleep":
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am curious about something here! Why write a renderer for something like this?  if you want an application wide disabled auto-lock like the questioner has asked for just curious!

Comment: Native tasks are just for everything you can't do in forms. Have many other tasks implemented, posted the part you were asking for. Now when you hit the Forms wall with any native problem just put your native code inside INativeTasks and fly. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve it by using **`Xamarin.Essentials`** plugin. Install it on solution level(While installing select *include prerelease* checkbox).

In your `MainPage` write this code

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToggleScreenLock();
    }
    public void ToggleScreenLock()
    {
        if (!ScreenLock.IsActive)
            ScreenLock.RequestActive();
        else
            ScreenLock.RequestRelease();
    }
}
```

In Android project `MainActivity` add this line

```
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

before calling `LoadApplication(new App());`. For more information visit [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screen-lock?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms).

This is working throughout the app. To install plugin refer below screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Now Essentials not supported ScreenLock

Comment: @FetFrumos: It seems that it is now done with `DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer is deprecated in android

Below code works for me in Xamarin.Android

```
Window window = ((MainActivity)Forms.Context).Window;
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer android versions, you may use this:

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).