# Disable "sleep mode" on Tizen TV when app active

Tags: xamarin.forms, tizen

I create my first app for Tizen (with Xamarin Forms). When i run my app i need TV to stay all time active.

While the app is on, the sleep mode should not turn on on the TV.

Is it possible?
What api should I use?

Comment: This question is a great one. I wonder if you find something or not. Finding the answer to this over the internet is so hard!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution, but a way to go:

1. implement a possibility to call tizen native code from forms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534562/7149454
2. call tizen native api to set `efl_util_set_window_screen_mode(win,EFL_UTIL_SCREEN_MODE_ALWAYS_ON);`